# How to edit `postgresql.conf` with pgAdmin 3?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How does one edit the 'postgresql.conf' file with the pgAdmin app?

With pgAdmin 1.18.1 on Postgres 9.3.x, when I choose `File` > `Open postgresql.conf` I get a file picker dialog. And, yes, I'm connected in pgAdmin as the superuser 'postgres'.

I know I've done this in older versions of Postgres.

Comment: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/extend.html#extend

Comment: @MilenA.Radev No help there. The 'postgres' default database already had `adminpack` installed. I installed `adminpack` on my other two databases as well. Restarted pgAdmin. But, still, when I choose `File` > `Open postgresql.conf` I get a file open picker dialog. **Exactly what operation in pgAdmin** is supposed to open the postgresql.conf file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In pgAdmin…

- To edit the `postgresql.conf` file:
  Choose `Tools` > `Server Configuration` > `postgresql.conf`
- To edit the `pg_hba.conf` file:
  Choose `Tools` > `Server Configuration` > `pg_hba.conf`

**Avoid** the red-herring *File* menu:

- `File` > `Open postgresql.conf`
- `File` > `Open pg_hba.conf`

[image: screen shot of menu item: Tools > Server Configuration > postgresql.conf]

Comment: (FYI when making a change, the file needs to be saved before triggering the server to reload its configuration)

Comment: FYI, this feature depends on the 'adminpack' extension.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174503/125589