# Why is Server Configuration in Pgadmin3 inaccessible for me?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-3

My Postgres server is running (localhost:5432), but Tools > Server Configuration is greyed out for me as below. I was attempting to access it to edit/locate my postgres.conf file. [image: Can't access Server Configuration]

Comment: I think you need the adminpack extension installed on the server

Comment: Pursuant to postgres' assertion of a missing package of implementation tools, I thought I installed it by accepting the prompt - I guess this was not the case. Thanks!

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan could you detail how to install that extension in an answer? It would be helpful it it could be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *adminpack* extension

You need to install the [*adminpack*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) extension on the server.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS adminpack
```

Tips:

- Verify the extension is available for installation.
  `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions ORDER BY "name" ;`
- Verify installation.
  `SELECT * FROM pg_extension ORDER BY extname ;`

Comment: P.S. Azure blocks this for PostgreSQL hosted on their cloud =/

Answer (score 3):

## pgAdmin 4

In addition to installing `create extension adminpack` mentioned by @neil-mcguigan I had trouble finding the configuration values.

They have been in different places in different pgAdmin versions. (I'm currently on 4.1.6, although the question was about v3)

I'm adding this here in case someone else is looking.

- Choose your server in the left tree pane.
- The configuration tab is in the lower part of right side pane.

[image]