# How to edit `postgresql.conf` with pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, pgadmin-4

Same Question as this: [*How to edit `postgresql.conf` with pgAdmin 3?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61193/19079) but updated for the completely new (total re-write) [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org).

➥ How does one edit the configuration files with the *pgAdmin 4* app?

- postgresql.conf
- pg_hba.conf

I added the [*adminpack*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) extension as [discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174503/19079). And I restarted *pgAdmin 4*. Yet I cannot identify any menu item or other interface item for editing this files.

Comment: To change parameters in `postgresql.conf` you don't need to edit the file. [alter system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html)  will do the same thing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I added a workaround Answer based on that. Of course, that addresses only `postgresql.conf`, leaving `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Workaround: `ALTER SYSTEM`

As a partial workaround, [Postgres 9.4 added a feature](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-alter-system-set-for-dynamic-configuration/) to dynamically set the properties seen in `postgresql.conf`: [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) commands.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET configuration_parameter { TO | = } { value | 'value' | DEFAULT }

ALTER SYSTEM RESET configuration_parameter
ALTER SYSTEM RESET ALL  -- Clears all the settings set via `ALTER SYSTEM SET`.
```

This provides a convenient alternative to manually editing the `postgresql.conf` file.

Example:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = replica;
```

How does it work?

- A `postgresql.auto.conf` file is written by the `ALTER SYSTEM SET` command.
- This file and `postgresql.conf` are both read, so you can combine these approaches if desired. The `auto` file trumps the hand-edited file for coinciding properties.
- For reliability, a `postgresql.auto.conf.temp` file is created to rollback to the original state in case of error.

Caveats:

- Settings do *not* take effect immediately. [Read the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html).
- Must be superuser to execute.
- Cannot be called in a transaction block or function.
- Cannot set [`data_directory`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html#GUC-DATA-DIRECTORY).
- Obviously misuse can be dangerous to your database system, so be careful.

Tip: To read the value of the settings, see this Question, [*Query for all the Postgres configuration parameters‘ current values?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220933/19079)

## Workaround: Use command-line editor as `postgres` user

You can run a simple [text-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) like [*nano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) from the [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) run with the [privileges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) of the `postgres` user. Open the `pg_hba.conf` file, edit, and save.

For example, on a [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)/[POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-oriented OS such as [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) or [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS):

```bash
sudo -u postgres nano /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data/pg_hba.conf
```

For more info, see the Question, [*Switch user to 'postgres' user on macOS results in “su: Sorry” error*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221043/19079)