# Query for all the Postgres configuration parameters‘ current values?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, query

You can [set various configuration parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html) for Postgres by either editing the `postgresql.conf` file manually or by calling [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) commands. These are two avenues for *writing* the settings, but how about *reading*?

➥ Is there a way to query for all the current settings?

I know the settings in the client authentication configuration file `pg_hba.conf` can be read with the [`pg_hba_file_rules`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html) view, like this: `table pg_hba_file_rules ;`. Is there something similar for `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: `select * from pg_settings`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I posted an Answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## `SHOW ALL`

The [`SHOW ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-show.html) command displays the current setting of run-time parameters in 3 columns.

```sql
SHOW ALL ;
```

[image: screenshot of pgAdmin 4 running <code>SHOW ALL</code> command]

## `pg_settings`

The [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html) view shows the same items as [`SHOW ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-show.html) but with additional details, across 17 columns versus 3 columns.

```sql
TABLE pg_settings ;
```

[image: screenshot of pgAdmin 4 running <code>TABLE pg_settings</code>]

## `pg_file_settings`

To read what is stored in the `postgresql.conf` file itself, use the view [`pg_file_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-file-settings.html).

If freshly written, this file will hold values that may not yet be in effect within the Postgres server. After writing, the settings must be loaded in one of various ways including a server restart.

```sql
TABLE pg_file_settings ;
```

[image]

## Admin tool

Your databased-administration tool may display these settings.

For example, in [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org), choose the cluster name (the Postgres installation) in the navigation panel, click the `Dashboard` tab, and in a list bottom panel titled `Server activity`, click the `Configuration` tab to see a list of your settings.

[image: screenshot of pgAdmin 4 > [cluster name] > Dashboard > Server activity > Configuration]

## Writing

By the way… For info about *writing* these settings with `ALTER SYSTEM` commands, see [my Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220836/19079) on another Question, [*How to edit `postgresql.conf` with pgAdmin 4?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220700/19079).

Comment: Is `TABLE pg_file_settings;` equivalent to `SELECT * FROM pg_file_settings;`?

Comment: @RTD Yes. The first is a convenient shortcut specific to Postgres, the second is standard SQL.

Comment: Cool, thanks. If you have a piece of documentation for this shortcut, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @RTD Well, I tried to find that command in the manual. But searching for “TABLE” in Postgres doc results in an endless number of hits.

Comment: @RTD Found it, after I thought to use the Index chapter of the doc. The `TABLE` command is documented on the page for [`SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html). Search that page for “TABLE Command”, about 3/4 down the page.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, I tried to search too but I was getting numerous false positives. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a command like `SHOW '%log%', say, if you just want paramters like logging? I've tried different ways but nothing works?