# Switch user to 'postgres' user on macOS results in "su: Sorry" error

Tags: postgresql, permissions, users

The [Postgres installers](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) kindly provided to the community by EnterpriseDB.com creates a `postgres` user account on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) as is common.

In a console session in [*Terminal.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)), I need to switch to that user. My goal is to run a text editor with that user’s privileges so that I can edit the `pg_hba.conf` file controlling Postgres user-authentication rules.

When I try:

```bash
su - postgres
```

…I am prompted for the user's password, which I enter successfully, yet get the error message:

> su: Sorry

I am sure the password is correct. What can I do to access the `postgres` user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `sudo su postgres`

Having found this [closed Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7765269/642706) and [its duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23982282/642706), I will post here the solutions found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765367/642706) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23982810/642706).

➥ You must use the `sudo` command *combined* with the `su` command.

```bash
sudo su postgres
```

When prompted, enter your **macOS admin user password** rather than the `postgres` user’s password. At this juncture, your Mac admin user is the one executing the `sudo` command, not the `postgres` user.

While I do not understand why we must combine the `sudo` with the `su`, it does indeed work for me in [macOS Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave). I did not find this tip among my various BSD and Linux related searching efforts, so perhaps this is a Mac-only Apple thing, perhaps an extra security measure. Or perhaps in the Unix-style OSes, the `su` command must be run by the `root` user, and in macOS the `root` account is disabled by default for security purposes – our Mac admin user account is less powerful than `root`, and may not be authorized by default to run `su`? Dunno, don't care, the workaround works.

### Modern alternative: `sudo -u`

According [to Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23988605/642706) and [to Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23982810/642706), the more modern form is:

```bash
sudo -u postgres -i
```

According to [this page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html):

- `-u` means “run a specified command as this specified user”.
- `postgres` is specifying the username under which we want to run the command.
- `-i` simulates an initial login, meaning the shell will be initialized running that user’s startup scripts.
- No command is provided, so an interactive shell is executed.

For more discussion on the older and newer approaches, see this Question on sister site, [*What's the difference between sudo su - postgres and sudo -u postgres?*](https://serverfault.com/q/601140/142214). The answer there by Craig Ringer advises: (a) Forget about `sudo su`, and (b) use `sudo -u` instead.

#### Run apps as `postgres` user

To run a [`psql`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#psql) session as the `postgres` user:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql
```

To run the [`nano`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) [text-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) app as the `postgres` user:

```bash
sudo -u postgres nano
```

Answer (score 7):

The EBD installer asks for a password during the installation but it is meant for the database user, not the `postgres` Unix user, which doesn't have a password.

This is mentioned in [Postgres, Passwords and Installers](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgres-passwords) on EDB site. Quote:

> On Unix-like operating systems such as Linux and Mac OS X, the account
>   is setup **without a password** and users generally never need to worry
>   about it again.

The most plausible explanation to `su - postgres` not working is for you  is that you're confusing the database password with the OS password.

To make `su - postgres` usable, the OS password would need to be set first, which could be done with:

```
$ sudo passwd postgres
```

This is also true for PostgreSQL packaged in Linux distributions. In fact, the PostgreSQL packages for Linux even go one step further and don't ask a password for the database superuser, which allows for a fully automated installation. Just like the OS password is not necessary if `sudo` is always used, a database password is not necessary if only the default `peer` authentication method is ever used by the `postgres` user.