# Edit pg_hba.conf file using pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, pg-hba.conf

[This other Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220700/19079) has Answers about viewing and editing settings in `postgresql.conf` file using [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) 4. But those Answers did not mention editing the [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file used for authentication of users.

➥ How to use *pgAdmin 4* for editing the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, *pgAdmin* cannot edit `pg_hba.conf`

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism by which pgAdmin can edit a `pg_hba.conf` file.  The reason why it's possible to edit `postgresql.conf` via pgAdmin is that the `ALTER SYSTEM` syntax is something that can be entered into a client interface.  Therefore, pgAdmin was able to "edit" `postgresql.conf` because it could send an `ALTER SYSTEM` query to the database.  No such syntax exists for editing access control.

Comment: So what is the usual mechanism for editing `pg_hba.conf`? Do folks just run a text editor like `nano` using permissions of the `postgres` user?

Comment: Yes, the typical method of editing `pg_hba.conf` is with the text editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The correct [Answer by richyen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252900/19079) explains how the host-based access settings of `pg_hba.conf` file are *not* editable by pgAdmin 4. So we must use a text-editor to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file directly.

## Example on macOS

Here is an example of using an editor to do so, the command-line tool [*nano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano), on macOS (and possibly on BSD).

The Postgres database system is installed along with a new system-level user, by default named `postgres`. That user owns the folders (has file system access privileges) containing the actual Postgres database files. So we must run as that user.

Switching users is surprisingly complicated if you are new to Unix-oriented OSes. For details, see: [*Switch user to 'postgres' user on macOS results in “su: Sorry” error*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221043/19079).

To switch users within a terminal session using `su`, we must do so by invoking the superuser's authority using `sudo`.

```
sudo su postgres
```

You will then be prompted for the password of the superuser.

Verify which user is currently running the session by doing:

```
whoami
```

Before editing, we should back-up the `pg_hba.conf` file. Make a copy, giving the file a similar name, with something like `.backup` appended.

1. Switch to the `data` folder nested within the `postgres` user’s home folder. Type:
   `cd ~/data`
2. To see a listing of files and verify `pg_hba.conf`, run: `ls`
3. Run:
   `copy pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf.backup`
4. Verify the backup by running `ls` again.

Now we can edit the original using the *nano* editor.

```
nano pg_hba.conf
```

You will see the file’s content appear on-screen. Notice the keystroke commands listed at bottom with `^` ([*Control* key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key)).

Use the down-arrow key to get to the end of the file (or press keys for `Next Page`). Use right-arrow key to move through the lines to edit. When done, press Control-O (for `write Out`) to save the file. See the reminder the Control+x will exit the nano editor.

At the command line, to stop running that session as the `postgres` user, run `exit`. Then verify again with `whoami`.