# Where is the pg_hba.conf file amendment on pg_admin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

On pg_admin3, you have an option to change / amend the pga_hba.conf file as you can see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61200/81730)

I tried to find a similar option in pg_admin 4 but to no avail.

Has the option disappeared?